# Data servers: Do query optimisers re-write queries removing redundant columns during the plan creation?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I kinda feel that they would, or at least it would seem logical that they would especially as it'd be crazy to fill a cache unnecessarily, but I can't find any evidence to say they would, neither can I find any real evidence either.

I have this test query running against a 290k row set that has a pk set on an identity field, and a composite index which whilst two of the fields from the derived table are covered as part of the index, the primary field under test is not:

The derived table in this instance has 7 redundant columns, and having ran these three DBCC commands to start with a cold cache:
`DBCC FreeProcCache; DBCC DropCleanBuffers; DBCC FreeSystemCache('sql plans');`

```
Select
a.provider_type
,Count(1) As count_of_provider_type

From (
    Select
    customer_id
    ,access_plan
    ,provider_type
    ,ap_postcode
    ,browser
    ,session_start_date
    ,session_end_date
    ,payment_method

    From adhoc..datacentre

)a

Group By
a.provider_type;
```

Returns this actual plan:
[image]

And from the profiler, CPU: 92, Reads: 23703

And then, having re-ran the three DBCC commands to return the cache to cold, running this re-expressed query:

```
Select
provider_type
,Count(1) As count_of_provider_type

From adhoc..datacentre

Group By provider_type;
```

Gives me this actual plan:
[image]

And profiler, CPU: 78, Reads: 23476

Notice any similarities?
Which given the batch count, io and cpu, leads me to wonder that the optimiser *did* rewrite the first query to remove the derived table and the redundant columns.
But how can I prove it. I can't find anything at learn.microsoft under the Query Processing Architecture to suggest that the optimiser would rewrite the query, neither can I find a way of seeing what was transferred to cache. Does anything exist that can definitely say exactly what was read and cached.

It'd be good to get a perspective from other tools as well.

And finally, the why. What nutjob would write the first query without having realised it could be re-expressed?
Views. As we all know, views can be abused. They shouldn't, and in an ideal world, views would only be used to provide a pre-built model ready to be used by something else, but we all know this never happens.
Just like a doctor who has a cream for that, so too have engineering built a view that includes that in its output, "so you don't need to go and create a new view".
So if the view is basic, maybe it's being used to replace a table, but includes scd:2 logic, and maybe its selecting non-engineering and/or PII data, if a user were to query this view for only a couple of fields, would the optimiser rewrite the query?

Also added to dba.stackexchange on a slightly better written question if you're interested: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/337435/data-servers-do-query-optimisers-re-write-queries-removing-redundant-columns-du

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Clearly SQL Server. This is probably best posted on [dba.se]

Comment: Given how trivial it is to implement such an optimization, I would imagine this is implemented in almost all good DBMSs, and runs well before any cost-based-optimization.

Answer (score 1):

All the optimizers of good RDBMS rewrite the queries to relieve them... Do not forget that SQL queries are translated into relational algebra, that is to say in the form of a mathematical formula (algebraic tree) by a module just called "algebrizer", which, like any mathematical expression can be simplified... Remember a² - 2ab + b² <=> (a - b)(a + b)...

In this part of the optimizer, two levels:

- heuristic: remove unnecessary things (for example removal of the
  DISTINCT operator if the SELECT clause contains the key...)
- semantic: take into account the constraints (PK, FK, UNIQUE,
  CHECK...) to simplify the query

Once this work has been undertaken, the optimizer will use more complex rules, based on the statistics hidden behind columns and indexes, by choosing the sequencing of the different steps and by selecting the most appropriate algorithms for each processing operation of each step of the execution plan...

To see this in action there are some undocumented trace flags (DBCC) but Microsoft does not show everything, because some optimizations are specific to MS SQL Server and result from expensive research that the publisher does not want to be plundered by other publishers or by free RDBMSs which make no R&D effort and only copy the big publishers...

Comment: Thank-you, yes, I know this, but I need to be able to reference this.

Now for the honesty, I'm in a debate / disagreement with another about something along these lines: Tableau and its Custom SQL object.
When using this, you paste your query to the cSQL object, and then, for every data action, what is sent is the top query.
I have proven definitely  that cSQL is far more performant than Tableau poorly designed data modeller, yet still users follow the line that cSQL is underperforming. If only I could prove visually that the rewriting is happening to remove redundancy

Comment: I know this is for Snowflake but you'd have thought that would behave broadly similar, this is one of a handful of whitepapers that seem to fail to grasp how query optimisers work: file: https://www.snowflake.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Best-Practices-for-Using-Tableau-With-Snowflake.pdf
pg 8 onwards, and to make things worse, probably to help their argument, they are using a Select * in the derived table.

Comment: You can’t know in advance if an RDBMS will rewrite a query or how it will re-write it - and you can’t guarantee that the same query will be rewritten in the same way every time (significant changes in data volume could affect the execution plan, for example). All you can do (as you’ve done) is compare the execution plan of two queries and if they are the same then they have both been rewritten in the same way (every query is rewritten to some extent)